# SQL Query, return data with changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to isolate only the source key values that changed from '900' to 'RCF'. My code now returns all records regardless of any changes.

```
select 

PD_END_DT, 
SOURCE_KEY_VALUE, 
Fed_Class_cd

from XXXXXXXXXXXX 
where (pd_end_dt = '2015-11-30' or PD_END_DT = '2015-12-31')
    and (FED_CLASS_CD = '900' or FED_CLASS_CD = 'RCF')
```

Sample Data:

```
 pd_ned_dt      Source_key_value        Fed_Cls_Cd

2015-11-30 CML0100000565101565000000000  900
2015-11-30 CML0100000613059250000613000  900
2015-12-31 CML0100000613059250000613000  RCF
2015-12-31 CML0100000613060250000613000  RCF
2015-11-30 CML0100000613060250000613000  900
2015-11-30 CML0100000613061250000613000  900
2015-12-31 CML0100000613061250000613000  RCF
2015-12-31 CML0100000613062250000613000  RCF
2015-11-30 CML0100000613062250000613000  900
2015-11-30 CML0100000633001633000000000  900
2015-12-31 CML0100000633001633000000000  900
2015-12-31 CML0100000641001641000000000  RCF
2015-11-30 CML0100000641001641000000000  900
2015-11-30 CML0100000641002641000000000  900
2015-12-31 CML0100000641002641000000000  RCF
2015-12-31 CML0100000641003641000000000  RCF
```

What is a query I can use to display only the records I would like to see? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add sample data also

Comment: `'900' to 'RCF'` doesn't make any sense add sample data and expected result

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you have multiple records in the table for each key value, so you need a query that checks for key values where code = 900 and the date < 12/31/2015 and the same key value was inserted as RCF when the date = 12/31/2015?

Comment: @Pரதீப் Updated my question to show data and hopefully explain my question a little more

Comment: @JacobH I have multiple records for each Source Key Value but I need a query that isolates source key values that changed from 900 to RCF. The date is actually irrelevant.

Comment: You need a field to track the changes like a timestamp or anything else to hold the old state

Comment: i think if you change pd_ned_dt datatype to datetime then its possible to track such changes

Comment: @Ashu I am unable to change data format

Comment: @MaurícioPontaltiNeri unfortunately there is no other field to track such changes and I am unable to add one to the database. Thanks though for the suggestion

Comment: you can try to remove the condition FED_CLASS_CD = '900' because you want only the registers with in FED_CLASS_CD = 'RCF'. Is not the best solution but in this scenario is better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NULL 
BEGIN   -- DROP TABLE #TestData;
    CREATE TABLE #TestData (
         pd_ned_dt DATE NOT NULL,
         Source_key_value CHAR(28) NOT NULL,
         Fed_Cls_Cd CHAR(3) NOT NULL 
        );
    INSERT #TestData (pd_ned_dt, Source_key_value, Fed_Cls_Cd) VALUES
        ('2015-11-30', 'CML0100000565101565000000000', '900'),
        ('2015-11-30', 'CML0100000613059250000613000', '900'),
        ('2015-12-31', 'CML0100000613059250000613000', 'RCF'),
        ('2015-12-31', 'CML0100000613060250000613000', 'RCF'),
        ('2015-11-30', 'CML0100000613060250000613000', '900'),
        ('2015-11-30', 'CML0100000613061250000613000', '900'),
        ('2015-12-31', 'CML0100000613061250000613000', 'RCF'),
        ('2015-12-31', 'CML0100000613062250000613000', 'RCF'),
        ('2015-11-30', 'CML0100000613062250000613000', '900'),
        ('2015-11-30', 'CML0100000633001633000000000', '900'),
        ('2015-12-31', 'CML0100000633001633000000000', '900'),
        ('2015-12-31', 'CML0100000641001641000000000', 'RCF'),
        ('2015-11-30', 'CML0100000641001641000000000', '900'),
        ('2015-11-30', 'CML0100000641002641000000000', '900'),
        ('2015-12-31', 'CML0100000641002641000000000', 'RCF'),
        ('2015-12-31', 'CML0100000641003641000000000', 'RCF');
END;

--=============================================================

SELECT 
    ChangeDate = td1.pd_ned_dt,
    td1.Source_key_value,
    BeforeChange = td2.Fed_Cls_Cd,
    AfterChange = td1.Fed_Cls_Cd
FROM 
    #TestData td1
    JOIN #TestData td2
        ON td1.Source_key_value = td2.Source_key_value
WHERE 
    td1.Fed_Cls_Cd = 'RCF'
    AND td1.pd_ned_dt >= '2015-11-30'
    AND td1.pd_ned_dt < '2016-01-01'
    AND td2.Fed_Cls_Cd = '900'
    AND td1.pd_ned_dt > td2.pd_ned_dt;
```

Comment: hmm didn't give me any results.

Comment: Updated answer based on new test data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct pd_ned_dt , Source_key_value  ,  Fed_Cls_Cd from xxx As a 
where   
Exists(select Source_key_value from xxx where Source_key_value=a.Source_key_value and Fed_Cls_Cd='900')
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for

Comment: This returned only records with RCF as the fed_class_cd, not quite. I need something that returns the source_key_values and fed_class_cd that changed from 900 to RCF and display both results

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT *
FROM #XXXXXXXXXXXX q900
    INNER JOIN #XXXXXXXXXXXX qRCF
        ON q900.SOURCE_KEY_VALUE = qRCF.SOURCE_KEY_VALUE    
        AND q900.pd_end_dt < qRCF.pd_end_dt
        AND q900.FED_CLASS_CD = '900' 
        AND qRCF.FED_CLASS_CD = 'RCF'
```

NB: If PD_END_DT isn't relevant at all, you need some other way of knowing that the RCF record against that Key is newer than the 900 record. Any other fields that could be used for that?

Comment: There are no other fields that would differentiate the change in the field unfortunately.

Comment: Is it true that a '900' will only change to an 'RCF' (and not the other way round), and there aren't any other codes? Or could an RCF change to a 900, or a 900 change to some other code?

Comment: it could change to a lot of different options

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you looking for? I'm not sure if I understood your question..

```
SELECT 
mt2.*
FROM 
dbo.MyTable mt1
JOIN dbo.MyTable mt2
ON mt1.SOURCE_KEY_VALUE = mt2.SOURCE_KEY_VALUE 
AND mt1.FED_CLASS_CD = 'RCF' // data that changed from RCF
AND mt2.FED_CLASS_CD = '900' //data that changed to 900
AND mt1.PD_END_DT < mt2.PD_END_DT // data that happened after, so updated
WHERE 
AND mt1.PD_END_DT >= '2015-11-30'
AND mt1.PD_END_DT < '2016-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try The Below query , just an idea you can complete on it. Hope it helps you

```
;with testD
as
(
   select *
  , row_number() over(partition by Source_key_value order by pd_ned_dt) rowNumber
   from XXXXXXXXXXXX
)
select prevData.*,currentData.* 
  from testD  currentData left join testD  prevData on 
  currentData.Source_key_value= prevData.Source_key_value and currentData.rowNumber=prevData.rowNumber+1
  where prevData.Fed_Class_CD ='900'
```